# Styling lightning:outputField checkbox

Tags: checkbox, style, outputfield

I am using lightning:recordViewForm to display case data;

And inside the lightning:recordViewForm, i use lightning:outputField to display fields data, like this:

```
<lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{!v.caseId}" objectApiName="Case">
      <lightning:outputField fieldName="myBooleanField" />
</lightning:recordViewForm>
```

And the checkbox render looks like this :[image]

the marker is in the white color, and it is not realy readable;

I want change the marker white color, or simply remove the slds style, how i can achieve that?

The lightning:outputField doesn't have the class attribute to override css style;

the rendred html code lokke like :

```
 <div class="slds-form-element__control">
        <lightning-input class="slds-form--inline slds-form-element__static">
        <div class="slds-form-element">
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
        <span class="slds-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="input-1" disabled="">
        <label for="input-1" class="slds-checkbox__label">
        <span class="slds-checkbox--faux"></span>
        <span class="slds-form-element__label slds-assistive-text">MyFieldLabel</span>
        </label>
        </span>
</div>
</div>
</lightning-input>
</div>
```

Thank you;

Comment: Wrap the `lightning:outputField` with a div of class=slds-box and try different background color to make it readable.

Comment: No it doesn't work, it surround label + checkbox with border, i thing that the solution is to do something with style, i have try this :
.THIS .slds-checkbox.checkbox-checked .slds-checkbox--faux{
    border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}, but it doesn't work for me;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something as follows to change the marker colour and the background of the checkbox.

As A.Bretto mentioned wrap your **`lightning:outputField`** inside a div with your custom class.

Though you can use the following approach to change the styles to your wishes. 
It is generally advised to use native HTML elements to style your preferences and take caution when overriding styles of components which you don't own such as `lighnting:outputField` or any lightning, ui namespaces.

The following approach uses hierarchies( CSS specificity ) to manipulate the styles. So a general warning, if Salesforce decides to change any of the class names (*which can happen without notice*) shown in the snippet below or if the hierarchy of the DOM structure changes in the future releases your styles will not work as expected. You might have to adjust accordingly.

> **Component**

```
<aura:component access="global" >
    <lightning:recordViewForm recordId="500xx000000xXxxx" objectApiName="Case">
        <div class="slds-box parent">
            <lightning:outputField fieldName="isBug__c" />
        </div>
    </lightning:recordViewForm> 
</aura:component>
```

The parent class mentioned in the div will be the point of reference in your CSS styles so that you do not disrupt any other styles.

> **Style (CSS)**

```
/* For checkbox background */
.THIS .parent .slds-form-element .slds-form-element__control .slds-checkbox .slds-checkbox__label .slds-checkbox--faux{
    background : red;
}
/* For checkbox marker color */
.THIS .parent .slds-form-element .slds-form-element__control .slds-checkbox .slds-checkbox__label .slds-checkbox--faux:after{
   border-color: #dcff1b;
}
```

> **Output**

[image: Checkbox Customized]

Comment: Hi, It didn work for me...I posted a similar question. From HTML inspect I can change the color but not in the aura. Do you have any solution for that ?             https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/254458/unable-to-change-the-styling-for-lightning-outputfield-for-checkbox-inside-light

Comment: Looks like you are missing the whole point of having a wrapper div and parent class - this example uses a div with class "parent" to add specificity to the previously styled elements. You might have to adjust it according to your structure.

Comment: Hi , I think I forgot to mention that yes I did tried with adding a wrapper div <div class="slds-box parent"> before the ightning outputfield and used the same stylesheet above. It doesn't worked. I have checked now again